# How to extract values when there are two matches in a string

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am running linux `ls -la | grep 'Jul  6'` command to grep the file names

I am using re 
`[drwxr-]+[\s0-9]+(\w+)[ 0-9 \w]+[:0-9]+ (\S+)`

to catch two values, id and filename in this case 'mwhat' and 'scripts' in the first statement

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 mwhat 24500 4096 Jul 6 21:04 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 15 araza 24500 4096 Jul 6 21:04 IMAGEs
```

And then use group to catch them,

```
name = str(out.group(1))
file = str(out.group(2))
```

this works fine till I have 1 entry in the `ls` output. How can I handle more than 1 entry as mentioned in my output about?

Purpose of the script is to fetch files from the location as per the date, if there are more than 1 entry for the date it should not fail

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using `findall()` function

```
pat = re.compile(r'[drwxr-]+[\s0-9]+(\w+)[ 0-9 \w]+[:0-9]+ (\S+)')
for (name, file) in re.findall(pat, output):
    print(name, file)
```